# CodeIgniter Redirection from form input

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've never used a PHP framework, but I wanted to learn how to use one so I could more easily program for my company, so I chose CodeIgniter.

I am following the code igniter tutorial for a news section so I could learn how things work - but I am having some issues/questions.

Now, I am to the point in the tutorial that I have a form that submits and takes me to a success page. In normal PHP this is where I would just redirect the page to the view page of the news item submitted. In CodeIgniter I have a view function in my controller here

```
        public function view($slug = NULL)
        {
                $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);

                if (empty($data['news_item']))
                {
                        show_404();
                }

                $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
```

I'm not sure how to get the slug from the form when it is submitted.

Here is my create function (Basically the one that inserts the database info and redirects to `news/success`)

```
        public function create()
        {
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $data['title'] = 'Create a news item';

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'Text', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
            {
                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('news/create');
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');

            }
            else
            {
                $this->news_model->set_news();
                $this->load->view('news/success');
            }
        }
```

But I want this to redirect to the view page. To do that I need to have the slug I believe. So it should redirect to `news/view/$slug` - but I'm not sure how to do this.

My set_news model:

```
        public function set_news()
        {
            $this->load->helper('url');

            $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);

            $data = array(
                'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                'slug' => $slug,
                'text' => $this->input->post('text')
            );

            return $this->db->insert('news', $data);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like that:

```
redirect('news/view/'.url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE));
```

Comment: And that should go on my success.php page? or? Sorry, I'm not really sure why I can't wrap my head around this whole framework thing but I'm sure I will understand eventually.

Comment: Also, how do you know that my form is POST?

Comment: yes it should be on success.php after news is inserted successfully.
regarding the form type, it is just an assumption, If it is **GET** you should use:
`redirect('news/view/'.$this->input->get('slug'));`

Comment: Based on my model, it is POST. However, this does not work for me, it redirects me to `news/view` but it doesn't add the slug. I don't think the success page gets the POST information and I think that is where I am struggling the most with this

Comment: after seeing the function set_news() (I think it wasn't available when I posted my reply), I knew that slug is not available in the form, that is why you should create it - as happening in set_news - therefore my suggested code is:
`redirect('news/view/'.url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE));`

Comment: I put that in my create() function, and it worked, thank you.